# How to get carousel working again after upgrading Bootstrap to version 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am working on upgrading a site from Bootstrap version 3.x to version 4.3.1. I overwrote the old Bootstrap files and also changed the jQuery script reference from 1.x to 3.3.1.

My problem is this: the jQuery that was working before the upgrade is now not working. Specifically, we have a carousel that is not running now.

The console shows nothing going wrong. No errors or warnings regarding Javascript.

Here is the HTML for the carousel:

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <!-- Indicators -->
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol>

              <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
              <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                  <img src="/i/slider1.jpg" alt="Jobs for veterans testimonial">
                  <div class="carousel-caption slide1">I had put my resume on 7 other major job boards and the BEST results came from<br><em>Michael</em>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <img src="/i/slider2.jpg" alt="Job offer former military testimonial">
                  <div class="carousel-caption slide2">I posted my resume on . I received a job offer in 2 days.<br> <em>C. Dean</em></div>
                </div>
                   <div class="item">
                  <img src="/i/slider3.jpg" alt="better job testimonial">
                  <div class="carousel-caption slide3">Thanks to I found a better job within a matter of weeks.... I highly recommend  &ndash; it truly works.<br><em>J. Spivey</em></div>
                </div>
              </div>

        </div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 8000,
    pause: "hover"
})
});
```

How can I get the carousel working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem was the class `item` has to be replaced by class `carousel-item` inside the `carousel-inner` wrapper. Also, there are other few things you may need to take into account if you read the documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/) like:

**1)** Add `d-block` and `w-100` classes to the images.

**2)** Define `width` and `height` attributes of the images.

## Working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 8000,
        pause: "hover"
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300" alt="Jobs for veterans testimonial" width="600px" height="300px" class="d-block w-100">
      <div class="carousel-caption slide1">
        I had put my resume on 7 other major job boards and the BEST results came from<br><em>Michael</em>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300" width="600px" height="300px" alt="Job offer former military testimonial" class="d-block w-100">
      <div class="carousel-caption slide2">
        I posted my resume on . I received a job offer in 2 days.<br> <em>C. Dean</em>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300" alt="better job testimonial" width="600px" height="300px" class="d-block w-100">
      <div class="carousel-caption slide3">
        Thanks to I found a better job within a matter of weeks.... I highly recommend  &ndash; it truly works.<br><em>J. Spivey</em>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

## Example 2:

Centered images on carousel using `text-center` class on `carousel-item` and `img-fluid` on the images for responsiveness.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 8000,
        pause: "hover"
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide bg-warning" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active text-center">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300" alt="Jobs for veterans testimonial" width="600px" height="300px" class="img-fluid">
      <div class="carousel-caption slide1">
        I had put my resume on 7 other major job boards and the BEST results came from<br><em>Michael</em>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item text-center">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300" width="600px" height="300px" alt="Job offer former military testimonial" class="img-fluid">
      <div class="carousel-caption slide2">
        I posted my resume on . I received a job offer in 2 days.<br> <em>C. Dean</em>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item text-center">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300" alt="better job testimonial" width="600px" height="300px" class="img-fluid">
      <div class="carousel-caption slide3">
        Thanks to I found a better job within a matter of weeks.... I highly recommend  &ndash; it truly works.<br><em>J. Spivey</em>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I obviously should have dug deeper into the documentation. I appreciate your help!